# ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_object'

Tags: python, pandas, importerror, file-handling

Using pandas to read excel file and getting the following error. Using ipython notebook and conda environment for it

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_object'#

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    demand = pd.read_excel("/home/raviraj/Machine_Learning/PSC/data/(Testing).xlsx",
                           sheet_name="Dec 19",skiprows=1)
    for col in demand.columns: 
        print(col)
```

The detailed error as below. I do not know how pandas work. I followed some tutorials, blogs only. This code was working fine previously but, do not know what happed giving such error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3ed19bf0634e> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 
      4 demand = pd.read_excel("/home/raviraj/Machine_Learning/PSC/data/(Testing).xlsx"
      5                        ,sheet_name="9th Dec 19",skiprows=1)

~/anaconda3/envs/TuriCreatePY35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     40 import pandas.core.config_init
     41 
---> 42 from pandas.core.api import *
     43 from pandas.core.sparse.api import *
     44 from pandas.tseries.api import *

~/anaconda3/envs/TuriCreatePY35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py in <module>()
      8 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isna, isnull, notna, notnull
      9 from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical
---> 10 from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
     11 from pandas.io.formats.format import set_eng_float_format
     12 from pandas.core.index import (Index, CategoricalIndex, Int64Index,

~/anaconda3/envs/TuriCreatePY35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 # flake8: noqa
----> 2 from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
      3     Grouper, GroupBy, SeriesGroupBy, DataFrameGroupBy
      4 )

~/anaconda3/envs/TuriCreatePY35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in <module>()
     44 from pandas.core.base import (PandasObject, SelectionMixin, GroupByError,
     45                               DataError, SpecificationError)
---> 46 from pandas.core.index import (Index, MultiIndex,
     47                                CategoricalIndex, _ensure_index)
     48 from pandas.core.arrays import ExtensionArray, Categorical

~/anaconda3/envs/TuriCreatePY35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py in <module>()
      1 # flake8: noqa
----> 2 from pandas.core.indexes.api import *
      3 from pandas.core.indexes.multi import _sparsify

~/anaconda3/envs/TuriCreatePY35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py in <module>()
      2 import warnings
      3 
----> 4 from pandas.core.indexes.base import (Index,
      5                                       _new_Index,
      6                                       _ensure_index,

~/anaconda3/envs/TuriCreatePY35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in <module>()
     51 from pandas.core.base import PandasObject, IndexOpsMixin
     52 import pandas.core.common as com
---> 53 from pandas.core import ops
     54 from pandas.util._decorators import (
     55     Appender, Substitution, cache_readonly, deprecate_kwarg)

~/anaconda3/envs/TuriCreatePY35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in <module>()
     21     maybe_upcast_putmask,
     22 )
---> 23 from pandas.core.dtypes.common import (
     24     ensure_object,
     25     is_bool_dtype,

ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_object'
```

Comment: I am not sure for but may be something is with your `pandas` library please reinstall it and then try to run your code.

Comment: try to use pip install pandas==1.0.1 (version depends) instead of conda.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest anyone who undergo this error to uninstall pandas and reinstall pandas >= 0.25.3 by pip (not by conda).

Comment: Please add suggestions as a comments to main question

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with your `Pandas` setup. It might have been occurred due to any/some of the following reasons.

1. Updating Python version, but not updating the PATH.
2. Some issues in installing/updating Pandas.
3. Issues in setting up Conda environment.

I would suggest that you first try to confirm whether the PATH for Python and Python modules is set correctly. If it is good, then I think reinstalling `Pandas` and repairing your Python installation will be much less time-consuming than trying to find out the exact cause.